# Performance comparision between scala & Java 8, map & filter

Tags: scala, lambda, profiling, java-8, higher-order-functions

I am profiling the the time it takes for java, using the new stream functionality, to perform map and filter for a list of integer. I do the same for Scala.

Java:

```
  List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
  for(int i = 1; i<10001; i++){
      list.add(i);
  }
  Stream<Integer> s = list.stream().map( x -> x * x);
  long start = System.nanoTime();
  s.collect(Collectors.toList());
  long elapsedTime = (System.nanoTime() - start)/1000;
```

Scala:

```
  val list = ArrayBuffer.range(1,10001);
  var start = System.nanoTime
  list.map(x => x*x);
  var elapsedTime = (System.nanoTime - start) / 1000;
```

My question: Is this comparison fair? 
It's my undersdanding that ArrayBuffer is Scalas "equivalent" to Javas ArrayList. stream().map interprets my lambda expression and implments the algorithm, stream.collect executes it, this is the the part that I should compare to ArrayBuffer.map?

After some feedback:

Java:

```
   for(int i = 0; i<times; i++){

        start = System.nanoTime();
        list.stream().mapToInt( x -> x + 1).toArray();
        elapsedTime += (System.nanoTime() - start)/1000;
    }
    System.out.  println("Java 8: Perform N + 1 for each element using      stream::mapToInt::toArray: " + elapsedTime/times + " micro sec");
```

Scala:

```
  for (i <- 0 until times){
   start = System.nanoTime;
   list.map(x => x + 1  ).toArray;
   elapsedTime += (System.nanoTime - start) / 1000;
  }
  println("Scala: Perform N + 1 for each element using map::toArray took: " + elapsedTime/times + " micro sec");
```

This changed the outcome alot.

Before the changes:

Java,  Map, 161 micro sec

Scala, Map, 148 micro sec

After the suggested changes:

Java,  Map, 21 micro sec

Scala, Map, 165 micro sec

the variable times was set to 100 000

Comment: You should be careful with extremely short benchmarks. There will be measurement errors caused by timer resolution, clock jitter, JIT compilation, context switches to other processes, etc. All of these will combine to make short benchmarks extremely misleading. I'd recommend you take a look at the jmh microbenchmark harness: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/ .

Comment: Yes, I intend to simulate the test several thosand times and then take the average. My concern was that the comparision between ArrayBuffer.map and stream.map for ArrayList was "unfair".
Thank for the link, I will look in to that.

Comment: Currently Scala compiles lambdas differently from Java 8. The latter emits bytecode which uses `invokedynamic` to dynamically create lambda classes in runtime. Scala also has this implemented, but it will become default starting from 2.12 (AFAIK). Until then Scala will continue to compile lambdas into pre-jdk8 anonymous classes.

Comment: In Java, I recommend using [IntStream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) instead of [Stream](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html). Otherwise the performance will be dominated by _object creation_ and _garbage collection_.

Comment: If I were doing it, I would convert to an Array first. In that small percentage of code in a real application that is worth the effort and reduction in straightforwardness to optimize for performance, you will be leaning toward Arrays. Also, I would map x to x+1 rather than x*x to minimize the amount of irrelevant work being done in the benchmark.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will try these sugestions and compare the results

Comment: "If I were doing it, I would convert to an Array first".

Could you explain this further. Arrays does not have the stream functionality in Java. 
I now convert it to an array in the end since I use the intStream

Comment: When you are using a specialized `range` factory in Scala, I suppose doing a similar thing in Java when comparing, e.g. `IntStream.range(1, 10001).map(x->x+1).toArray()` does the same. No need for filling an `ArrayList` with boxed `Integer`s.

Comment: This type of quick + simple microbenchmark using a simple timer like System.nanoTime() gives notoriously low precision, low accuracy results. You should use something like Oracle's jmh framework which is designed for exactly this sort of thing, gives much more accurate+precise results, and is not that hard to use.